# JavaFX CellFactory switch function returning Object error with NULL even though it shouldn't be NULL

Tags: java, listview, javafx, listcellrenderer

I'm currently developing a Log class called `NotesHistoryController`, which contains items from the type `NotepadHistory`. `NotepadHistory` objects contain the changed `Notepad` object, a timestamp and the logged in user who changed the note object.

`Notepad`s must be prioritized, such as "good" or "Bad" etc. and the priority is recognizable on the color which is displayed in the `ListView` i.e. defined in the `cellFactory`.

The way how I'm creating `NotepadHistory` objects is like this: User changes the current note object, db is updating the old object and then I'm defining / creating a `NotepadHistory` object with its attributes + a foreign reference to the changed `Notepad` object:

```
Dao<Notepad, Integer> notepadDao = db.getNotepadDao();
Dao<NotepadHistory, Integer> notepadHistoryDao = db.getNotepadHistoryDao();
NotepadHistory notepadHistory = new NotepadHistory();

//Saving the Notepad which is to be edited to delete it from the listView in the main window
Notepad ersatz = this.notepad;
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

//Saving the notepad after edits
this.notepad.setNotepadName(noteName);
this.notepad.setClassification(priority);
this.notepad.setNotepadContent(textContent);

try {
    notepadHistory.setNotepad(this.notepad);
    notepadHistory.setTimestamp(timestamp);
    notepadHistory.setUser(db.getLoggedInUser());
    notepadHistoryDao.create(notepadHistory);

    notepadDao.update(this.notepad);
```

Now there is a button which after being clicked, should show a `ListView` with `NotepadHistory` objects. All of this happens in the `NotesHistoryController` class. Here is my issue: After clicking on the history button in the application, it is giving me a `NullPointerException` in my `cellFactory`. After debugging I found out, that the referenced notepad object of the current `NotepadHistory` object doesn't contain any listings except the notepad Id. After hours of debugging etc., I still don't know where the problem lays. This is my `cellFactory`:

```
notesHistoryListView.getItems().addAll(db.getNotepadHistoryDao().queryForAll());

notesHistoryListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<NotepadHistory>, ListCell<NotepadHistory>>() {
    public ListCell<NotepadHistory> call(ListView<NotepadHistory> param) {
        return new ListCell<NotepadHistory>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(NotepadHistory item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                String style = "";
                if (!empty && item != null) {
                    setText(item.getNotepad().getNotepadName());

                    switch (item.getNotepad().getClassification()) {
                        case GOOD:
                            style = "-fx-background-color: green";
                            break;
                        case MEDIUM:
                            style = "-fx-background-color: yellow";
                            break;
                        case BAD:
                            style = "-fx-background-color: red";
                            break;
                        case NEUTRAL:
                            style = "-fx-background-color: grey";
                            break;
                    }
                } else {
                    setText("");
                }
                setStyle(style);
            }
        };
    }
});
```

The weird thing is, that it doesn't give me an exception for the `setText(item.getNotepad().getNotepadName());` line. It's just for line `switch (item.getNotepad().getClassification())`.

Comment: `item.getNotepad().getClassification()` seems to return `null`. Not enough info in there to find out more. Also no idea how `Dao` is implemented. It could contain the issue.

Comment: Hi Fabian, thanks for your reply. I just solved the issue; I had to add "foreignAutoRefresh" in my model for the Classification key.